# Benefits of EF Code First?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm just starting to learn EF and now readind about Code First workflow. From what I gather, you would design your objects first and then the database would be created based on those objects. I can't seem to see the good in this. Why would you let your database schema be dictated by the hierarchy of your objects? Would you be able to optimize your database using Code First?

Also, as I have not read far enough yet, does Code First fully support DBMS features (indexes, triggers, sp, etc)? I ask as I've read in some articles that this is what most preferred (Code First). I have seen something about Code Second which is from what little I've read, I think is much better (existing database, but code centric development?), but maybe I'm missing something or haven't yet read enough and you guys can clear those things up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The capabilities of code first are the same since you have the same ability to express all the features of EF manually in your code. The main difference is that you don't use a designer to generate your EF code. This offers some benefits since you can decouple your entity classes from the EF context. The main benefit of this is that you can use plain old c# classes that aren't necessarily tied to EF if you decide to switch to another orm down the line.
The downside of course is that you have to hand code the entire model.

Keep in mind that you don't have to generate the database from your code. You can code against an existing database.